# Matlabs patch() for R: Fill polygon with color gradient

Tags: r, matlab, colors, polygon, patch

I really like R and I want to fill an arbitrary polygon with a color gradient just as matlabs `patch()` is doing:

```
patch('vertices', [1 1; 1.5 2; 2 1],
      'FaceVertexCData', [0.1; 0.5; 3],
       'FaceColor', 'interp')
```

Fill polygon with color gradient: Easy with matlab, hard with R

[image: Fill polygon with color gradient: Easy with matlab, hard with R]

So I have a value for each vertex a.k.a. node of the polygon and some kind of interpolation of these values is used for the color of the face of the polygon (i.e. a color gradient between the nodes, not a constant color).

For R, the solutions for that problem I found in the Internet seemed very work-around-ish and moreover computationally slow (e.g. use many small polygons with different colors to draw one big polygon that it looks like a color gradient). Note: I need to plot ~500000 polygons that way...

Thanks a lot,

Chris

Comment: Show what you tried!

Comment: It's fast in rgl. Also, may be fast enough see bottom of this readme for examples using triangles https://github.com/mdsumner/polyggon/blob/master/README.md